# QGIS WMS mapserver not showing all layers

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-3, mapserver

I'm publishing a map via qgis_mapserv.fcgi and the WMS behaves strangely, without giving me any errors or other clues as to what might be wrong.

I am wondering:

- is the problem with using GeoJSON as a storage format?
- is the problem with my .qgs file?
- is the problem with the mapserver?

First, it doesn't advertise all the layers. I have defined a bunch of layers:
[image]

but when I access the WMS in QGIS to test it, it only shows me a few of them:
[image]

interestingly, one of the layers it does advertise isn't even published in properties:
[image]

I am doing nothing inbetween. I have QGIs on my desktop and qgis_mapserv.fcgi on my server. I simply upload the entire directory, .qgs file and all .geojson files and then load it in QGIS as a WMS layer to test.

I do get proper responses to Capabilities, etc. so the server itself appears to be working:
[image]

My second problem is that some of the layers, especially polygon layers, don't show up at all, even if I add them. It might be related.

Comment: Many experiments later, it appears that GeoJSON indeed has at least a part in this. qgis_mapserv also seems to be particular about filenames in a way that makes no sense.